# Disparar função JQuery quando botão for clicado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function(){
               $("input[name='numeroRg']").blur(function(){
                    var $nomePaciente = $("input[name='nomePaciente']");
                    var $dataNascPaciente = $("input[name='dataNascPaciente']");
                    .....
```

No momento, ela está sendo disparada quando o `input` que tem o nome de `numeroRG`perde o `focus`, eu gostaria que ela fosse disparada quando o usuário clicasse no `button pesquisarName`

```
<form>
     <div class="tab-content"> 
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="htab1">
               <div class="row" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="numeroRg">RG:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numeroRg" id="rg" placeholder="__.___.___-_">
                         </div> 
                         <button class="btn btn-info" name="pesquisarName" id="pesquisarId">Pesquisar</button>
                    </div>  
               </div>
          </div> 
</form>
```

Já tentei colocar do seguinte modo, mas não funcionou:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function(){
               $("button[name='pesquisarName']").click(function(){
                    var $nomePaciente = $("input[name='nomePaciente']");
                    var $dataNascPaciente = $("input[name='dataNascPaciente']");
                    .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu button está submetendo o formulário, você tem duas alternativas, cancelar a submissão, mudar o tipo o button.

**Cancelando submissão**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
               $("#ev").submit(function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                     alert('seu evento');
                    });
                   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ev">
     <div class="tab-content"> 
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="htab1">
               <div class="row" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="numeroRg">RG:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numeroRg" id="rg" placeholder="__.___.___-_">
                         </div> 
                         <button class="btn btn-info" name="pesquisarName" id="pesquisarId">Pesquisar</button>
                    </div>  
               </div>
          </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

**Adicionando um tipo para button**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
               $("button[name=pesquisarName]").click(function(ev){
                     alert('seu evento');
                    });
                   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
     <div class="tab-content"> 
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="htab1">
               <div class="row" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="numeroRg">RG:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numeroRg" id="rg" placeholder="__.___.___-_">
                         </div> 
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="pesquisarName" id="pesquisarId">Pesquisar</button>
                    </div>  
               </div>
          </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para efeito de teste em "Executar" omiti a tag `form`

Você pode chamar função pelo ID utilizando [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Você pode disparar a função no click do botão com `id="pesquisarId"` substituindo a linha

`$("input[name='numeroRg']").blur(function(){`

por esta linha

`$('#pesquisarId').click(function() {`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pesquisarId').click(function() {
       //.......
       //.......
       //para testar
       console.log('Botão id="pesquisarId" clicado e função disparada');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


     <div class="tab-content"> 
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="htab1">
               <div class="row" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="numeroRg">RG:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numeroRg" id="rg" placeholder="__.___.___-_">
                         </div> 
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="pesquisarName" id="pesquisarId">Pesquisar</button>
                    </div>  
               </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```